# ssh, displaying the files in a PHP-regex friendly way

Tags: php, ssh

The goal is to have a files array containing every file on it's own row. The ssh command executed is the following:

```
ls
```

Returning me a string. I tried a regex splitting with one or more space, but it's breaking files containing spaces and I don't want that.

The string returned by the  command above is as follows:

```
29.jpg 30.jpg 31.jpg 38.jpg 38_1.jpg 39.jpg 39_1.jpg 40.jpg 40_1.jpg 4193FC36BA6-E284-45FB-B740-E5C7CAE3C72C Banner jr and sr2.jpg Banner jr and sr2_1.jpg ImSy00005582.CR2 ImSy00005582_1.CR2 ImSy00005587.jpg
```

And what I'm simply looking for is a bulletproof way to have each file/directory/whatever on it's own line in an array.

`$files = preg_split('/\s+/', $file_string);` is not giving what I'm looking for unfortunately.

I can change both the PHP-code and ls command above if necessarery, but I need suggestions on how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you getting this string from linux `ls`, and want to convert it in to an array, right?
You can do that:

```
$str = "29.jpg 30.jpg 31.jpg 38.jpg 38_1.jpg 39.jpg 39_1.jpg";
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
```

But in my opinion you shouldn't use it like that. I'm talking about the `ls`.
If the files is stored in your sever, here is what you can do:

```
function FullListing($path) {
    $path = $path . ($path[strlen($path) - 1] == '/' ? '' : '/');
    $dh = @opendir($path);
    $arr = array();
    while ($ent = @readdir($dh)) {
        if ($ent !== '.') {
            $filePath = realpath($path . $ent);
            $tmp = array('name' => $ent, 'type' => filetype($filePath), 'path' => $filePath, 'size' => ToKB(filesize($filePath)));
            array_push($arr, $tmp);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

This function will return an array of arrays, that contain file name, file path, file type and size. Remove what you don't need and here you go!